# Flink SQL CLI client CREATE TABLE from Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-flink

I am trying to create a table in Apache Flink SQL client. I want to filter my JSON data in Flink, which arrives *continously* from a Kafka cluster.
The JSON looks like this:

```
{"lat":25.77,"lon":-80.19,"timezone":"America\/New_York",
"timezone_offset":-14400,
"current.dt":1592151550,
"current.sunrise":1592130546,
"current.sunset":1592179999,
"current.temp":302.77,
"current.feels_like":306.9,
"current.pressure":1017,
"current.humidity":78,
"current.dew_point":298.52,
"current.uvi":11.97,
"current.clouds":75,
"current.visibility":16093,
"current.wind_speed":3.6,
"current.wind_deg":60,
"current.weather.0.id":803,
"current.weather.0.main":"Clouds",
"current.weather.0.description":"broken clouds",
"current.weather.0.icon":"04d"}
```

The part I am interested in :

```
"current.weather.0.description":"broken clouds"
```

I want to filter my data whenever the `current.weather` description is `"moderate rain"`. I tried to create two tables in Flink:

1. the Rain table, where the whole JSON arrives, and
2. where my filtered data will be stored and sent back to another Kafka cluster.

```
CREATE TABLE Rain (current.weather.0.description varchar) WITH ('connector.type' = 'kafka',
  'connector.version' = 'universal',
  'connector.topic' = 'WeatherRawData',
  'format.type' = 'json',
  'connector.properties.0.key' = 'bootstrap.servers',
  'connector.properties.0.value' = 'kafka:9092',
  'connector.properties.1.key' = 'group.id',
  'connector.properties.1.value' = 'flink-input-group',
  'connector.startup-mode' = 'earliest-offset'
);
```

```
CREATE TABLE ProcessedRain(
  current.weather.0.description varchar
) WITH (
  'connector.type' = 'kafka',
  'connector.version' = 'universal',
  'connector.topic' = 'WeatherProcessedData',
  'format.type' = 'json',
  'connector.properties.0.key' = 'bootstrap.servers',
  'connector.properties.0.value' = 'kafka:9092',
  'connector.properties.1.key' = 'group.id',
  'connector.properties.1.value' = 'flink-output-group'
);
```

The error message I get :

```
[ERROR] Could not execute SQL statement. Reason: org.apache.flink.table.api.SqlParserException: SQL parse failed. Encountered "current" at line 1, column 20. Was expecting one of:
    "PRIMARY" ...
    "UNIQUE" ...
    "WATERMARK" ...
    <BRACKET_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <BACK_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
    <IDENTIFIER> ...
    <UNICODE_QUOTED_IDENTIFIER> ...
```

How should my `CREATE TABLE` be created correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it should be

```
CREATE TABLE ProcessedRain (
  `current.weather.0.description` VARCHAR
) WITH (
  'connector.type' = 'kafka',
  'connector.version' = 'universal',
  'connector.topic' = 'WeatherProcessedData',
  'format.type' = 'json',
  'connector.properties.bootstrap.servers' = 'kafka:9092',
  'connector.properties.group.id' = 'flink-output-group'
);
```